# Ordinary differential equation using numerical solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

$$ x_{k+1} = x_k + \frac{h}{2} [f(t_k,x_k) +f(t_{k+1},x_k +f(t_k,x_k)h)]  $$

$$ x_{k+1} = x_k + \frac{h}{2} [3f(t_k,x_k) -f(t_{k-1},x_{k-1}) ]  $$

I want to know are these formulas having the properties of Runge-Kutta method or implicit Euler method or any other method. I know the simple Euler formulas but have no idea which formulas are these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is the explicit trapezoidal method or [Heun's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun's_method) and thus an explicit Runge-Kutta method of order 2.

The second is not a one-step method as it employs values at (time) indices $k-1,k,k+1$. It is an explicit linear multi-step method, and as such the order 2 [Adams–Bashforth method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_multistep_method).